# uppercasing a character in string with a letter of users choosing

Tags: python-2.7

I'm pretty new to programming in python, so this is giving me problems. I'm searching for a way to uppercase a letter of a user's choosing in a word of user's choosing. For example, user writes `staircase` and as character he writes `a` and the end result would be `stAircAse`.

I know the code to ask user a question

```
promt='enter word:\n'       
originalString=raw_input(promt)

promt='enter a character:\n' 
upperCharacter=raw_input(promt)
```

But other then that I'm lost and would appreciate help.
i tried this code, but its not the user input of a letter to upper case

```
def chartoupper(instring,inchar):
indexes=[3,7]
chars=list(originalString)
for i in indexes:
chars[i]=chars[i].upper()
string=''.join(chars)
return string
promt='enter word:\n'  
originalString=raw_input(promt)
promt='enter a character:\n'
upperCharacter=raw_input(promt)
newstring=chartoupper(originaString,upperCharacter)
print originaString
print upperCharacter
print newstring
print inchar
```

Comment: Sorry, that was just my mistake for being careless writing here too fast. I have tried uppercasing a letter by index, but that is not the user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
if(len(upperCharacter) == 1):
    finalString = originalString.replace(upperCharacter, upperCharacter.upper())
print finalString
```

As you should check if the user has indeed just added a single character, we added the if condition.

We are replacing all the occurrences of the character upperCharacter in originalString and assigning it to finalString. Refer the docs for [this method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace)

Answer for edited question --

```
def chartoupper(instring, inchar):
    string = instring.replace(inchar, inchar.upper())
    return string

promt='enter word:\n'
originalString=raw_input(promt)
promt='enter a character (note that only the 1st character will be used):\n'
upperCharacter=raw_input(promt)[0]
newstring=chartoupper(originalString, upperCharacter)

print originalString
print upperCharacter
print newstring
```

Comment: You can simply ignore all user input except the 1st character and so omit the `if`: `upperCharacter=raw_input("Enter a character (note that only the 1st character will be used: ")[0]`